# Repeated measures test with different number of measurements

Tags: statistical-significance, repeated-measures

I have a set of 40 measurements for each individual. These were sleep times of humans for successive nights.

I would like to test whether the first 5 measurements are significantly different from the last 35. which test should I use?
I would use a [repeated measures test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design) but it needs the same size for the 2 measurements

Comment: Do you wish to make this test separately for each individual or for the individuals as a group?

Comment: I would like to do separately for each individual

Comment: So, your question reduces to "how do I compare the first five measurements to the last 35."  The answer depends on your model: if there is little prospect of dependence between the two sets, this is a routine comparison of two batches of data.  If there is dependence, that will matter for the comparison: how are you modeling it?  Finally, exactly what do you mean by "different": on what basis?

Comment: the variable measured is the sleeping time, would it be enough to perform a 2-sample t-test between the first 5 measurements and the last 35?

Comment: It depends on the experiment.  If these were sleep times of humans for successive nights, you should anticipate serial correlation.  If they were sleep times for one night each month over three years, then serial correlation might be less of an issue.

Comment: these were sleep times of humans for successive nights

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.